# Bug with Spring 3.2.3, EhCache 2.6.3, Perhaps?

Tags: spring, ehcache

I tried to convert my ehcache xml to Java Config. I have the following code.

```
@Bean
public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCache(){
  EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCache = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
  ehCache.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
  ehCache.setShared(true);
  ehCache.setCacheManagerName("CACHE_MANAGER");

  return ehCache;
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(){
  EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager();
  cacheManager.setCacheManager(ehCache().getObject());

  return cacheManager;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager cannot be cast to org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean
```

My dependency for ehcache is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The error goes away when I do the following:

```
private EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCache;    

@Bean
public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCache(){
  ehCache = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
  ehCache.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
  ehCache.setShared(true);
  ehCache.setCacheManagerName("CACHE_MANAGER");

  return ehCache;
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(){
  EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager();
  cacheManager.setCacheManager(ehCache.getObject());

  return cacheManager;
}
```

Is this a bug with spring or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might have been a fluke. I restarted my ide and it no longer complained about this issue.